# How to handle "except" in Regular Expression in Compiler Design?

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, regular-language

I'm working on Compiler Design and can't figure out how I can handle except statements in RE.

For example:
An RE of a literal having only 3-digit binary numbers except (011,001,010)

I know that the RE of 3-digit binary number would be either:

- (0|1)(0|1)(0|1)

or

- (0|1){3}

But how can I handle "except" here?

Comment: Using 3 times either 1 or 0 will have 8 combinations. You want to exclude 3 or them, so you could consider just listing the other 5. If you have a larger set, you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` and use a character class `[01]` instead of `(0|1)` Like `^(?!0[01]1|010)[01]{3}$` https://regex101.com/r/B9oFSZ/1 But matching them is shorter `^[10]00|1[01][01]$`

Answer (score 1):

Using 3 times either 1 or 0, can have 8 combinations. To match the valid 5 combinations, you can either list all 5 of them or use a pattern to match a 1 followed by all combinations of 1 and 0 or match 000.

```
^(?:1[01][01]|000)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FLAQvj/1)

If you have longer strings, you might also use a negative lookahead, for example

```
^(?!01[01]|001)[01]{3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rKC6ap/1)

**Note** that you can use `[01]` instead of using an alternation `(0|1)`